# Outlook add-in launchevent.js not loading/triggering on desktop client Windows

Tags: windows, outlook, office-js

I've developed a new Outlook add-in (started with the plain typescript, yeoman template with webpack) which uses a taskpane for the Read- and the write (Compose) window.

The Read mode works perfectly on all versions (web and desktop) including the desktop client on Windows, Mac, ...

The Write mode, which uses the SmartAlerts (launchevent.js) (`OnMessageSend` and `OnNewMessageCompose` handlers) also works on most versions, just not on the desktop client on Windows.

When composing a new message, it takes forever for the add-in to load and once it's loaded, it does not trigger the `OnNewMessageCompose` event. Then when sending the email, it fails after a minute due to the "add-in is unable to process the message" (or something like that, executes nothing because one of the first sections is making an API call that never reaches our server).

I've transpiled the code to all different ES versions and ran an ES-check, which was all fine. I've made sure that there are no 'ternary operators', I've included the `Office.actions.associate` calls for the two handlers. The functions are registered in the manifest,...

I've tried attaching a debugger, but my VS code won't attach while the add-in/Outlook is running in debug mode (followed the knowledge/help file, but it's missing a step, is outdated, or there is just something that's different/not working on my end), but the enabled runtime logger is not reporting any issues related to the add-in.

I've worked before with the "old" `itemSend` handler via the `commands.html` file, which did not have this issue, but we want the add-in to be listed on AppSource, hence the use of the new SmartAlerts.

I've then stripped everything from my `launchevent.js`, only including the basics, but I still have the issue.

It currently looks like this:

```
function onNewMessageComposeHandler(event) {
  try {
    if (Office.context.mailbox.item) {
      Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("info", {
        type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
        message: 'Show alert message here!',
        icon: "Icon.16x16",
        persistent: true
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {}
}

function onMessageSendHandler(event) {
  
}

if (Office.context && (Office.context.platform === Office.PlatformType.PC || Office.context.platform == null)) {
  Office.actions.associate("onMessageSendHandler", onMessageSendHandler);
  Office.actions.associate("onNewMessageComposeHandler", onNewMessageComposeHandler);
}
```

The relevant manifest parts look like this (identical to the documentation):

```
<Runtimes>
            <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url">
              <Override type="javascript" resid="JSRuntime.Url"/>
            </Runtime>
          </Runtimes>
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />

<!-- Enable launching the add-in on the included event. -->
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
              <LaunchEvents>
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewMessageCompose" FunctionName="onNewMessageComposeHandler"/>
                <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageSend" FunctionName="onMessageSendHandler" SendMode="SoftBlock" />
              </LaunchEvents>
              <!-- Identifies the runtime to be used (also referenced by the Runtime element). -->
              <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"/>
            </ExtensionPoint>
</DesktopFormFactor>

..


<bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://{server-address}/outlook-dev/commands.html?&amp;_v=1.0.13.466" />
          <bt:Url id="TaskpaneRead.Url" DefaultValue="https://{server-address}/outlook-dev/taskpane.html?mode=read&amp;_v=1.0.13.466" />
          <bt:Url id="TaskpaneWrite.Url" DefaultValue="https://{server-address}/outlook-dev/taskpane.html?mode=write&amp;_v=1.0.13.466" />
          <bt:Url id="WebViewRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://{server-address}/outlook-dev/commands.html?&amp;_v=1.0.13.466" />
          <!-- Entry needed for Outlook on Windows. -->
          <bt:Url id="JSRuntime.Url" DefaultValue="https://{server-address}/outlook-dev/launchevent.js?&amp;_v=1.0.13.466" />
        </bt:Urls>
```

And this does not work (testing on Outlook Office 365)

Not sure what I'm missing, or what the reason could be, but I've exhausted all my options code-wise, so there must be something "stupid and simple" that I'm missing..

Some extra information:

- The bundle.js is correctly downloaded in the %localdata% directory with the latest changes
- Tried calling the association functions without using the platform check

Edit due to a new discovery:

So I deep-dived in the event viewer, runtime logger etc and found that I get an error `"Access to one of your manifest's resources is denied. .."` in my ClientLog and an error in the event-viewer `"We're sorry, we couldn't access {add-in}. Make sure you have a network connection."` . It seems to be related to the resource for the `launchevent.js`, because the error changed when I entered an invalid URL for that resource and the `taskpane.html` and `commands.html` work.

I tried hosting the launchevent.js file on multiple servers (all different server configs) and still received the same error. I then also tried so that there are no query params attached to the resource URL, same issue. The file is publicly accessible, all the request headers and methods are allowed, ...

Are there any checks, limitations or special request items that the desktop client on Windows is using to fetch the `launchevent.js` file in the background resulting in it not being able to, or is this just a "generic error" when there are other issues at play?

Edit a couple of hours later:

I found an article somewhere related to authentication and SSO about the `.well-known/microsoft-officeaddins-allowed.json` so added that to the server with the `allowed` path to the `launchevent.js` and the add-in as application. I now no longer receive RuntimeErrors about being denied (success, the documentation should also maybe reference this part for the JSRuntime.Url resource...), but still have the EventViewer error related to the "We're sorry, couldn't access {add-in}".

I've inspected the requests via Fiddler Classic, and I can see all the requests to the necessary files and they are all 200 OK, so everything is loaded, but still, the launchevent does not trigger it's functions.

Comment: Can you share the Office version number for your Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this isn't something "stupid and simple" because I've tried lot of things and I'm experiencing the same issue as you. Events firing in like 1 try out of 100, sometimes even rarer. This happen both in debugging and in production variant.
I've created an issue in: [their github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3395), but they don't respond for 3-4 months and looks like nobody is interested in this topic. In my opinion it's something related with runtimes of the javascript office.js library. When it loads faster the event will fire, and when connection is unstable/slower etc. (so like 99% situations) the events won't fire, which would explain my problem.

Comment: Did you get it to work? We've assisted on a similar issue at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3677 and provided some extra information on how to troubleshoot issues like this.

Comment: I managed the events onNewMessageCompose and onNewAppointmentCompose to work, but onMessageRecipientsChanged seems to still don't work. The thing is i totally don't use Taskpane and without it it's hard to debug problem, because attached debugger only shows when using Taskpane